# How to get first N lines per unique KEY 'column' value in a text/CSV file?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, csv, unix

If you have a CSV/textual file with multiple columns, i.e.

```
domain, user
abc.com.au, Bob
abc.com.au, Marley
abc.com.au, Someone
nexle.dk, Daniel
nexle.dk, Dan
nexle.dk, John
nexle.dk, Doe
google.com, Larry
google.com, Sergey
```

How do you get the first 2 entries by column 1 (domain)?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for ages on Linux/Mac shell scripting solutions (looking at awk, curl, sort, uniq etc) but couldn't seem to easily do it myself so here is an app I wrote to do this:

https://github.com/danieliversen/MiscStuff/blob/master/scripts/findTopUniques.java

Basically, if you want to get the top X number of unique entries, once you've sorted the file using 'sort' or whatever.. Its Java so works on any platform (just need to compile with the JDK - doesn't require any 3rd party libraries).

Answer (score 0):

If your input file (e.g. `domname.csv`) has all the domains grouped on successive lines (as in your example), then:

```
$ tail -n +2 domname.csv | awk -F, 'BEGIN{dom=""; n=1} $1==dom && n<2 {print; n++} $1!=dom {print; dom=$1; n=1}'
```

Produces (from your example):

```
abc.com.au, Bob
abc.com.au, Marley
nexle.dk, Daniel
nexle.dk, Dan
google.com, Larry
google.com, Sergey
```

In this solution, the `tail` is just to get rid of the header (`domain, user`), and the `awk` command splits each line on the comma (`-F,`), then prints a line 1) when it sees a domain (first field, `$1`) for the first time (setting the count `n=1` and `dom`); or 2) if it has seen the domain in a preceding line (`$1==dom`) and `n<2`, incrementing `n` (to 2) so no further matching lines will be printed.

If the domains are not grouped on successive lines, i.e. if they can be interleaved like:

```
abc.com.au, Bob
nexle.dk, Daniel
abc.com.au, Marley
nexle.dk, Dan
```

Then you can still rescue the situation with a `sort` in the pipeline after the `tail` but before the `awk`:

```
$ tail -n +2 domname.csv | sort | awk -F, ...
```

Hope this helps.